# How to make VS2022 (or 2019) work with Docker on WSL2?

Tags: docker, visual-studio, wsl-2

recently I've tried to make Visual Studio 2022 work with Docker containers on WSL2.
My idea was to do a `docker-compose up` in my project's folder from WSL2. It runs well. Then I use d the WSL profile from VS to debug my project (by modifying the `launchUrl` and the `ASPNETCORE_URLS` properties in the WSL profile from `launchSettings.json`, in order to reach the running container from WSL2.

Currently I'm able to reach and debug my container but at the `app.Run()` instruction I get a `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'Permission denied'`.

What could it be?

Did anyone try to make Visual Studio (not VSCode) work (=debug) with Docker and WSL2?

I didn't find any information on this case except from this good post: https://medium.com/@frcs6b/docker-engine-on-wsl-visual-studio-2019-without-docker-desktop-dfdbef353350

So any help is very welcome! :-)

Comment: Same problem here, I created a new project and added support for Docker which creates a Dockerfile. But it requires the Docker Desktop installed, I'd like to use(=debug) wsl2 and the docker installed inside it rather

Answer (score -1):

A preview for supporting this is now available: [[Preview] Run containers in WSL with VS Container Tools](https://github.com/microsoft/DockerTools/issues/417)

Short version:
As of VS 17.10 Preview 1 you can set the environment variable `VSCT_WslDaemon` to `1` and VS will use volume mounts compatible with a daemon running on WSL.